# Trying to split file path into a tuple using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

I'm trying do recursion exercises and I'm stuck on a problem. I need to split a
file address into a tuple and I end up getting a tuple within a tuple. 
Below is what I have come up with and when I test it, it returns this:

enter path: C:/Users:/Games

('C:', ('Users:', 'Games'))

I want: ('C:','Users:','Games')

```
def split_path(s):
    path = ()

        if s.find("/") == -1:
        path= (s)
    else:
        location = s.find("/")
        path += (s[:location],)
        path += (split_path(s[location+1:]),)
return path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close. Take a closer look at your last line:

```
path += (split_path(s[location+1:]),)
```

You're putting the return value of the function, which is a tuple, inside another tuple.

Edit to add: I just noticed a very subtle error that probably lead you to putting the return value in a tuple:

```
path = (s)
```

should be

```
path = (s,)
```

This is how I would write it:

```
def split_path(s):
    index = s.find('/')
    if index == -1:
        return (s,)
    else:
        return (s[:index],) + split_path(s[index+1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

You would want to change the line close to the last line of your function to following:

```
path.extend(split_path(s[location+1:]))
```

Btw, why don't you use something like:

```
path = s.split('/')
```

Comment: That would work on a list, but not a tuple.  Tuples don't have an `extend` method.

Comment: Yeah now I realized the question is about `tuple`. In this case I will probably modify the function to return a list instead, and convert to tuple in the end.

Comment: i tried doing it as you suggested as a list but the last extension is split up by the letter, so in my example, after trying to split it, will be :


[ 'C:', 'Users:', 'g', 'a', ' m', 'e', 's']

Comment: For example, enter the following in Python console: `string = '''C:/Users:/Games''';string.split('/')`